# Is there anyway I can access File from Online SVN in python?

Tags: python, svn, urllib, sys.path

I've made a python module file and uploaded in the SVN Repo (say string_utl.py which does string related operation). Is the anyway that I can access the the file Direclty for the SVN. Though I checkout the file Locally from the SVN to my computer and access it from there. But that not the point. I'm thinking of a local repository where all of my coworkers can access and modify the code. 
I though add the Lsvn location in the sys.path list but it didn't worked.

I did it like this
sys.path.append ("http://lsvn/svn/lsvn/QRM_Helper/Helpful_Script/");

But didn't worked.

I tried it another way  like this
 urllib.urlopen(some_url) 
as I'm using Python 3 it  said to use urllib2.urlopen() but in my case it didn't worked either. It gave the following error that the module doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Just install the [pysvn module](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn.html) and then use normal SVN checkout, update, commit, etc.

You can't directly access the SVN backend datastore so please don't try.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using python3,the url handling code is `urllib.request.urlopen` (BTW, it should not have said to use urllib2.urlopen). `sys.path.append` takes local system paths only. It cannot take the urls. You can checkout the module to your local system and point to that path. [pysvn](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn.html) seems to be a way to programatically do svn operations using python, but still after you checkout the code, you should reference the directly the code is in, via local file-system path and add it to sys.path.

Comment: thanx anyway. But it seems like I'm having problem with urllib module. IT says urllib.request module missing.. http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html I've used this link. Am I missing some element??     File "<pyshell#40>", line 1, in <module>
    urllib.request.urlopen()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request' the following error pops up..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600389/python-error-when-using-urllib-open thanx anyways got the answer from here. In place of importing Import urllib.request I just importing urllib thanx for the help.. Highly Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

[`pip`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) `install -e svn+http://lsvn/svn/lsvn/QRM_Helper/Helpful_Script/#egg=local-name`

will create a checkout it (into `local-name/`) and install links into your Python so an import just works, and `svn update` also just works - no reinstall needed.
Caveat: don't know if that works on Windows.
Oh, and you'll need a setup.py file for it to work.

This won't pull the module every time; you can use pysvn or just run `svn update`.
But if you have more than one dependency, installing them with Pip will save your sanity :).

Answer (score 0):

I just got the answer.  I'll use the Pysvn to checkout the repo to a local folder. And I'll add the folder to sys.path list. Using this I can access the folders module.
Thank everyone for helping me out

But I've a slight problem... I didn't had the admin right in my office computer(I'm using windows) so I installed the pysvn in my laptop and copied the lib files from my laptop to my office computer..
Though I can pysvn in my computer (Office comp).but the Python crashes for no certain reason when I access Pysvn.. Is the copy paste could be the reason for that.