# urllib2.open error in python

Tags: python, url

I can't get URL

```
base_url = "http://status.aws.amazon.com/"
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(30) 
htmldata = urllib2.urlopen(base_url)
for url in parser.url_list:
        get_rss_th = threading.Thread(target=parser.get_rss,name="get_rss_th", args=(url,))
get_rss_th.start()

    print htmldata

<addinfourl at 140176301032584 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x7f7d56a09750>>
```

when specifying `htmldata.read()` ([Python error when using urllib.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600389/python-error-when-using-urllib-open))

then getting blank screen

python 2.7

whole code:https://github.com/tech-sketch/zabbix_aws_template/blob/master/scripts/AWS_Service_Health_Dashboard.py

The problem is, that from URL link (RSS feed), i can't get output (data) variable data = zbx_client.recv(4096) is empty- no status

Comment: Other than the indentation error, your code should work. It works for me locally, and [on repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/SeashellForkedCodewarrior).

Comment: Meanwhile, is there a reason you're using `urllib2` instead of installing `requests`, the way [`urllib2`'s own docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) suggest? It shouldn't make any difference here, but then your code should be working, so…

Comment: just put a link to whole class

Comment: First, please [edit] the relevant code—as a runnable [mcve]—into your question, don't just give us an external link.

Comment: Second, there is no attempt to `print htmldata.read()` in your linked code, so I still have no idea where your problem is. Is it just that you added a `print htmldata.read()` for debugging purposes after the `parser.feed(htmldata.read())`? If so, that's your problem: when you `read()` a file-like object, it reads the whole thing. After that, you're at the end of the file, so if you try to `read()` the whole file from there, you get nothing. If so, all you have to do to fix it is only read once, like `contents = htmldata.read()`, then you can `parser.feed(contents)` and `print contents`.

Comment: @abarnert, yes, i added print htmldata for debugging, your solution helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no real problem with your code (except for a bunch of indentation errors and syntax errors that apparently aren't in your real code), only with your attempts to debug it.

---

First, you did this:

```
print htmldata
```

That's perfectly fine, but since `htmldata` is a `urllib2` response object, printing it just prints that response object. Which apparently looks like this:

```
<addinfourl at 140176301032584 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x7f7d56a09750>>
```

That doesn't look like particularly useful information, but that's the kind of output you get when you print something that's only really useful for debugging purposes. It tells you what type of object it is, some unique identifier for it, and the key members (in this case, the socket fileobject wrapped up by the response).

---

Then you apparently tried this:

```
print htmldata.read()
```

But already called `read` on the same object earlier:

```
parser.feed(htmldata.read())
```

[When you `read()` the same file-like object twice, the first time gets everything in the file, and the second time gets everything after everything in the file—that is, nothing.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906137/why-cant-i-call-read-twice-on-an-open-file)

---

What you want to do is `read()` the contents once, into a string, and then you can reuse that string as many times as you want:

```
contents = htmldata.read()

parser.feed(contents)

print contents
```

---

It's also worth noting that, as the [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) documentation said right at the top:

> **See also** The [`Requests` package](http://requests.readthedocs.org/) is recommended for a higher-level HTTP client interface.

Using `urllib2` can be a big pain, in a lot of ways, and this is just one of the more minor ones. Occasionally you can't use `requests` because you have to dig deep under the covers of HTTP, or handle some protocol it doesn't understand, or you just can't install third-party libraries, so `urllib2` (or `urllib.request`, as it's renamed in Python 3.x) is still there. But when you don't have to use it, it's better not to. Even Python itself, in the [`ensurepip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ensurepip.html) bootstrapper, uses `requests` instead of `urllib2`.

With `requests`, the normal way to access the contents of a response is with the `content` (for binary) or `text` (for Unicode text) properties. You don't have to worry about when to `read()`; it does it automatically for you, and lets you access the `text` over and over. So, you can just do this:

```
import requests
base_url = "http://status.aws.amazon.com/"
response = requests.get(base_url, timeout=30)
parser.feed(response.content) # assuming it wants bytes, not unicode
print response.text
```

Answer (score -2):

If I use this code:

```
import urllib2
import socket
base_url = "http://status.aws.amazon.com/"
socket.setdefaulttimeout(30)
htmldata = urllib2.urlopen(base_url)
print(htmldata.read())
```

I get the page's HTML code.